# when is $n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m}\approx ne^{-\frac{m}{n}}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Iv'e encountered the following "identity" in some lecture notes (about the coupon collector problem, where $n$ is the number of bins and $m$ is the number of trials),

$$n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m}\approx ne^{-\frac{m}{n}}$$

Where the "$\approx$" is supposed to mean, as far as I can understand, "asymptotically with $n$"

Why is this true? Are there any conditions on $m$ as well as $n$?

Comment: Take the logarithm on both sides, and use expansion $\log(1-\varepsilon)=-\varepsilon - \dfrac{\varepsilon^2}{2} - \cdots$

Comment: This will also allow you to see how close this approximation is, depending on the $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $$a_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{m}\implies \log(a_n)=m \log \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ So, by Taylor expansion
$$\log(a_n)=-\frac{m}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)} \sim e^{-\frac{m}{n}}$$

Comment: Note that the asymptotic equality requires $m=o(n^2)$.